# Adding the Content-Type to the Swashbuckle Get Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I use Swashbuckle 5.0 and .Net Core 3.1

There is a Get method that is able to return the results in different formats (JSON and XML).

I have read that the newest versions of Swagger should be able to parse this code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

and produce proper Swagger configs and finally have something like [image] in the UI.

But this code somehow doesn't work. Am I missing something or is it simply a bug of the latest version of Swashbuckle and I should go with some workarounds?

**Update (thanks to Jawad):**
My Startup configuration of the Formatters looks like:

```
services.AddControllers(options => 
{
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
})
.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => { opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; });
```

I am not quite sure why there are 2 XML Formatters (maybe some merge issues), but it worked somehow until this moment.

Comment: How exactly does this not work? What result do you expect and what is the actual result?

Comment: I expect Swagger UI to have a dropdown with a response content type. And at the moment I don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Swagger UI only displays the media types when the return type is known. Since you are returning an ActionResult, Swashbuckle has no information what the return type is.
When I change the controller to

```
public async Task<T> Get()
```

or add the attribute

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(T))]
```

I am able to see the different response content types on my application

Comment: Seems that it is kind an option

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the `SupportedMediaTypes` to your `WebApiConfig.cs` file as well,

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
```

Comment: Hi @Jawad, I don't feel that I have WebApiConfig. Only Startup and Program

Comment: @BorisSokolov add it to your Startup.cs file. [ref](https://gist.github.com/robzhu/804171e2b90cc2a2958f)

Comment: I have a kind of formatters. And seems that I have found the issue as one of the formatters was leading to this behaviour.